# Expand and Collapse of 3 level hierarchical rows in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some hierarchical data in a table structure as so:
(example 1)

```
A 
  A.1 
    A.1.1 
    A.1.2 
  A.2 
    A.2.1
    A.2.2
B
  B.1
    B.1.1
    B.1.2
  B.2
    B.2.1
    B.2.2
```

I would like to be able to expand and collapse within each level, so example, If I click on A.2, it's children should collapse: (example 2)

```
A 
  A.1 
    A.1.1 
    A.1.2 
  A.2 
B
  B.1
    B.1.1
    B.1.2
  B.2
    B.2.1
    B.2.2
```

And if I click A, all of its children should collapse: (example 3)

```
A 
B
  B.1
    B.1.1
    B.1.2
  B.2
    B.2.1
    B.2.2
```

and if I expand A again, A.2 should still remain collapsed (children hidden) (example 4)

```
A 
  A.1 
    A.1.1 
    A.1.2 
  A.2 
B
  B.1
    B.1.1
    B.1.2
  B.2
    B.2.1
    B.2.2
```

I have tried code samples from http://jsfiddle.net/y4Mdy/1124/ -- but not handling three level hierarchies.  $(this).nextUntil seems to work nicely, but when the next tr is a parent row, it gets collapsed until the next child row. Also, if I collapse the 2nd level and then collapse the parent, the 2nd levels are hidden but the 3rd level displays:

```
A 
    A.1.1 
    A.1.2       
B
  B.1
    B.1.1
    B.1.2
  B.2
    B.2.1
    B.2.2
```

I have also tried http://jsfiddle.net/icc97/XNkbE/ -- but sub levels do not go back to collapsed state when clicking on parent level (similar to my example 4 above)

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This solution should handle any number of levels.

My original jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dmvianna/uL3uy2cs/). I will be updating it more often than this answer.

```js
$("tbody > tr:not([data-level='3'])").addClass("expandable sign folded");
$("tbody > tr:not([data-level='1'])").hide();
$("tbody > tr")
    .css("padding-left", function (index) {
    return 10 * parseInt($(this).data("level"), 10) + "px";
});

function range(lowEnd, highEnd) {
    // assert lowEnd >= 0 and highEnd < 100
    var validation = (lowEnd <= highEnd) && (lowEnd >= 0) && (highEnd < 100);
    if (!(validation)) {
        console.assert(validation, 
                       'Function "range" received unlikely values: ' +
                       lowEnd + ' and ' + highEnd + "...");
    } else {
        var arr = [];
        while (lowEnd <= highEnd) {
            arr.push(lowEnd++);
        }
        return arr;
    }
}

function name_range(fun, lowEnd, highEnd) {
    var arr = range(lowEnd, highEnd);
    jQuery.each(arr, function (index, value) {
        arr[index] = fun(value);
    });
    return arr;
}

function create_selector(level) {
    return "[data-level='" + level + "']";
}

$("tr.expandable").click(function () {
    var this_level = parseInt($(this).data("level"), 10);
    var this_level_selector = create_selector(this_level);
    var next_level_selector = create_selector(this_level + 1);
    var next_or_lower = name_range(create_selector,
    this_level + 1, 10); // TODO: find last level
    var this_or_higher = name_range(create_selector, 0, this_level);
    var node = $(this).prevUntil(this_or_higher.join(","));
    // different behaviour according to state (expanded / folded):
    if ($(this).hasClass("expanded")) {
        $(this).removeClass("expanded").addClass('folded');
        $(node).not("expanded").removeClass("expanded").addClass('folded');
        $(node).filter(next_or_lower.join(",")).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("expanded").removeClass('folded');
        $(node).filter(next_level_selector).show();
    }
});
```

```css
table, tr, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-color: gray;
}
tr:not([data-level='3']) {
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
tr.expanded .sign:after {
    content:"-";
}
tr.folded .sign:after {
    content:"+";
}
td:first-child {
    padding: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-level='3'>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-level='3'>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-level='2'>
            <td>sub stores<span class="sign"></span>

            </td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-level='1'>
            <td>Trade<span class="sign"></span>

            </td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-level='3'>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-level='2'>
            <td>sub stores<span class="sign"></span>

            </td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-level='3'>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-level='2'>
            <td>sub stores<span class="sign"></span>

            </td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-level='1'>
            <td>Stores<span class="sign"></span>

            </td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am also stuck between like this problem, Could you check thid link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096238/implement-header-for-the-custom-table-in-html-and-javascript?noredirect=1#comment91143776_52096238

Answer (score 1):

If we click on an element of the first level, we hide all visible elements on level 2 and 3. If the elements of the first level are already hidden we make the elements on level 2 visible again.

```js
    toggleElement = function(context) {
  let current = context.parentElement
  if (current.className == 'level1') {
    toggleLevel1(current)
  } else if (current.className == 'level2') {
    toggleLevel2(current)
  }
};

toggleLevel1 = function(current) {
  let nextSibling = current.nextElementSibling;

  while (nextSibling && nextSibling.className == 'level2') {
    nextSibling.hidden = nextSibling.hidden ? false : true
    nextSibling = nextSibling.nextElementSibling
    while (nextSibling && nextSibling.className == 'level3') {
      if (!nextSibling.hidden) {
        nextSibling.hidden = nextSibling.hidden ? false : true
      }
      nextSibling = nextSibling.nextElementSibling
    }
  }
};

toggleLevel2 = function(current) {
  let nextSibling = current.nextElementSibling;

  while (nextSibling && nextSibling.className == 'level3') {
    nextSibling.hidden = nextSibling.hidden ? false : true
    nextSibling = nextSibling.nextElementSibling
  }
};
```

```html
<html>
<header>
  
</header>
<style>
table, tr, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-color: gray;
}
.level2 td:nth-child(1){
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.level3 td:nth-child(1){
  padding-left: 10px;
}
</style>
<body>
<table border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="level1">
            <td onclick="toggleElement(this)">Trade

            </td>
            <td>total1</td>
            <td>total1</td>
            <td>data1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level2">
            <td onclick="toggleElement(this)">sub stores

            </td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level3">
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level2">
            <td onclick="toggleElement(this)">sub stores

            </td>
            <td>total2</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level3">
            <td>data3</td>
            <td>data3</td>
            <td>data3</td>
            <td>data3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level1">
            <td onclick="toggleElement(this)">Trade

            </td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td>total</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level2" >
            <td onclick="toggleElement(this)">sub stores3

            </td>
            <td>total3</td>
            <td>data3</td>
            <td>data3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level3">
            <td>data4</td>
            <td>data4</td>
            <td>data4</td>
            <td>data4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level2" >
            <td onclick="toggleElement(this)">sub stores5

            </td>
            <td>total5</td>
            <td>data5</td>
            <td>data5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level3">
            <td>data6</td>
            <td>data6</td>
            <td>data6</td>
            <td>data6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only dealing with nested `table`s, you can use this one:

CSS:

```
tbody.collapsed {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('thead').click(function(){

        $(this).siblings('tbody').toggleClass('collapsed');

    });
```

I used `thead` and `tbody` to make use of semantics.